# Can you host Sharepoint 2010 on Azure cloud?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, azure

As the title suggests, can Sharepoint 2010 be installed and successfully run on Azure cloud?

I am aware that Azure used to be stateless and as such could not support Sharepoint, but recent articles and posts seem to suggest that Mirosoft have resolved this.

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/06/27/microsoft_windows_azure_cloud_epiphany/

I have checked the Azure website and Sharepoint is mentioned but not specifically 2010 and I want to be sure it's a supported environment with no catches or unforeseen problems.

Comment: For SharePoint-specific questions, please see the [SharePoint Stack Exchange site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you aware of [Office 365](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/free-office365-trial-si.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

With the Spring 2012 release (which you read about with your link above), there are now Virtual Machines which are persisted to disks in Windows Azure blobs. SharePoint 2010 is one of the applications that's been specifically tested in this environment.

See [this support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2721672), where SharePoint 2010 (and other software) is explicitly called out.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this TechNet article on [creating a VM instance in Azure for a SharePoint farm](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/06/17/creating-an-azure-persistent-vm-for-an-isolated-sharepoint-farm.aspx) helpful.